# Parameter error in AMP for Drupal on Nginx

Tags: nginx, drupal, centos, amp-html

I'm trying to enable AMP pages on my drupal website on a VPS running on CentOS 7 and nginx.
Previous web server was Apache and I changed it to Nginx for better performance due to daily requests.
Before switching to Nginx, the amp page structure was:
`domain.com/content/slug/?amp`
after switching to Nginx, the link above does not work and gives 404 BUT, it works when I use &, " `domain.com/content/slug/&amp` "
I was wondering what could be the problem and how can I fix it?
PS:  in Order to use Clean URLs in Drupal I enabled:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: any help ? anyone?  :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was :

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}
```

So I removed it and added

```
location / {
# try_files $uri @rewrite; # For Drupal <= 6
try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7}
```